# how compare two variables which are inside two different functions i jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the code:

```
var selector = '.tabsclicked ul li';

$(selector).on('click', function () {
    $(selector).removeClass('activenav');
    $(this).addClass('activenav');

    var hashsign = "#";
    var contentid;  
    var linkshref;

    $('.contentdesc > div').each(function() {
        contentid = $(this).attr('id');
    });

    alert(contentid);

    $('.tabsclicked ul li a').each(function () {
        linkshref = $(this).attr('href');
    });

    var hrefval = hashsign+contentid ;

    if (contentid === linkshref){
        alert("true");
        $(contentid).removeClass('active in');
    } else {
        alert("false");
        $(contentid).addClass('active in');
    }
});
```

if i alert contentid its showing the last id evertime. But i want the respective id of the div when the li is cliked

Comment: Can you create a fillde at jsfiddle or provide the html code too

Comment: You need to traverse from `this` to find the elements you want. We would need to see your HTML structure to show you how to do that

Comment: You don't need either `.each()` loop. Use [DOM traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), which we can't help you with without seeing the structure of the HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d8obdLvc/

Comment: Its a huge code. Actually its a tabs content display. I have use bootstrap also. I have two tabs menus - one horizontal and one is vertical. whenever i click on 1st horizontal menu, the relative content displays in relative section which is correct. then i click on 1st menu of vertical nav, again the content display. then agian i clickon 1st menu of horizontal nav, content displays but now when i click on 1st menu of vertical nav, content doesnt display, it displays the content related to 1st nav of horizontal nav only

Comment: I have given href="#sectionA" for menu and id="SectionA" for content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perhaps want to activate the content div based on the anchor clicked. Here are my updates :

```
var selector = '.tabsclicked ul li';

$(selector).on('click', function () {
    $(selector).removeClass('activenav');
    $(this).addClass('activenav');
    var linkshref = [];
    var clickedHref = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

    $('.tabsclicked ul li a').each(function (i, el) {
        if ($(el).attr('href') != clickedHref) {
            linkshref[i] = $(el).attr('href');
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < linkshref.length; i++) {
        $(linkshref[i]).removeClass('active in');
    }
    $(clickedHref).addClass('active in');

});
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bko5g95e/4/

Comment: Vijay can you please explain the code  from if condition. where r u fetching the id?

Comment: in the if condition I am fetching all the anchor href except the one which is clicked. Since the href is "#" + contentId...so just need to loop through this href array and remove active class from each content. in the end, I added active class on the content which belongs to clicked href.

Comment: I am trying to learn thats why clearing my doubts. so you mean $(linkshref[i]) is fetching contentid

Comment: Yes, $(linkshref[i]) means $("#"+contentid) in your equivalent code.

Comment: but how it will recognize # symbol?

Comment: `linkhref[i]="#content1"` so you need not to append extra '#'

Comment: Vijay i have one more doubt, in my code how can i compare those variables which are inside two different functions?

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of the first `div` inside the clicked `li` do this:

```
var selector = '.tabsclicked ul li';
//Only one:
$(selector).on('click', function () {
     var myDivId = $(this).find('div').eq(0).attr('id');
     alert(myDivId);
});
//All divs, in an array
$(selector).on('click', function () {
     var myDivIds = [];
     $(this).find('div').each(function(){
         myDivIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
     });
     alert(myDivIds);
});
```

Comment: yaa but i want the id for all the divs

Comment: Actually i am able to get the id's and href's with above code. but as the variables are inside the each function, i am not able to compare them..

Comment: I have updated the code to show both. Notice that the trick is to use an array to list them all, and to declare it outside of the each scope, where you will need it.

Comment: thanks, now i got all the id's and href's. But i want to compare one by one id and href on click of li.